# How to update a specific element from List<T> element collections?

Tags: c#

I have a list of custom objects List and I would like to update a specific element say 3rd element from top, How would I do that in C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// Updates a property or member of the item
myList[2].myProperty = something;

// Replaces the item in the list
myList[2] = someNewItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`List<T>.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx) property.

Comment: The square-brackets use this internally.

Comment: Yep! (make this 15 characters, please)